# including html tag in a php code, specifically dealing with href function inside a php block

Tags: javascript, php, html

enter the html code once a condition is satisfied but then i aim to use php values and html tags together.

tried  tag etc and got most of the part in running just unable to deal with href beacuse it is referencing to some values.
not sure where to use "" or ``.

```
<?php.....        
echo `<a href="limitdatabase.php?Dropdown=.$_GET[Dropdown].;&search= $search_name;&wise=$_GET[wise];">Yes</a>`;

?>
```

"yes" should work as a hyperlink but at the moment the php values are not processed that`s why no result.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong sequence of quote

```
<?php

  ...

?>

<?php
  echo '<a href="limitdatabase.php?Dropdown=' .
         $_GET['Dropdown'].
         ';&search='. 
         $search_name .
         ';&wise='.
         $_GET['wise'].
         ';">Yes</a>';

?>
```

and you should use single quote and not backtics for string

Comment: <a href="limitdatabase.php?Dropdown=<?php echo $_GET['Dropdown'];?>&search=<?php echo "$search_name";?>
     &wise=
    <?php echo $_GET['wise'];?>">Yes</a></span>


this was working earlier but now i do not get any results after clicking "yes".

Comment: are you sure that the cotent of $_GET build a valid link  .. (anyway this seems a new question) to me ..

Comment: yes, that was working until i used the  href inside a php block.

Comment: i do not much knowledge about php and the syntax. i just have have a feeling that something very small is missing.

Comment: .. i don't understand  ..  this is a PHP block ..  so what do you mean .. ??? each time you need  this  code  just copy ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198381/discussion-between-sanjeev-gautam-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect concatenation. Whenever you want to add any `PHP` variable then you need to close the braces and need to start after `PHP` variable as below:

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="limitdatabase.php?Dropdown='.$_GET['Dropdown'].'&search= '.$search_name.'&wise='.$_GET['wise'].'">Yes</a>';
?>
```

Also you should wrap `Dropdown` and `wise` in braces as it will not work directly in get as you have used. Hope it helps you!

Comment: after clicking the hyperlink, do not see results.

Comment: Can you show output of print_r($_GET); echo $search_name; before hyperlink ??

Comment: the output was fetched data from database. i can share a screenshot if it would help?

Comment: It seems that values are missing in these variables. Take mouse over the link and it will show the complete link in left bottom of your browser. check if it is correct or share ss of the variable values.

Comment: though there are no errors but i guess this part of code is not working. 
';&search= '.$search_name.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should also remove `;` from this as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198384/discussion-between-sanjeev-gautam-and-rohit-mittal).

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of html with php inside:

```
<a href="limitdatabase.php?Dropdown=<?PHP echo $_GET[Dropdown] . "&search=" 
 . $search_name . "&wise=" . $_GET[wise]; ?>">Yes</a>
```

Also, you can input whole link in string:

```
<?php
$mylink = "limitdatabase.php?Dropdown=" . $_GET[Dropdown] . "&search=" . $search_name . "&wise=" . $_GET[wise];
?>
<a href="<?PHP echo $mylink; ?>">YES</a>
```